# What is the record for most turnovers by an NFL team that won the game?

Tags: nfl, records

In the [2014 NFC Championship game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2014%E2%80%9315_NFL_playoffs#NFC_Championship_Game:_Seattle_Seahawks_28.2C_Green_Bay_Packers_22_.28OT.29), the Seattle Seahawks committed 5 turnovers (4 interceptions and one fumble) and still won the game.  What is the record for most turnovers by an NFL team in a playoff game win?  What about for a regular season win?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Post Merger:

According to the Pro Football Reference Game Finder using [this query](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1970&year_max=2014&game_type=&playoff_round=&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&game_day_of_week=&game_time=&time_zone=&game_location=&surface=&roof=&stadium_id=&temperature_gtlt=lt&temperature=&game_result=W&overtime=&league_id=&team_id=&team_conf_id=&team_div_id=&opp_id=&opp_conf_id=&opp_div_id=&team_off_scheme=&team_def_align=&opp_off_scheme=&opp_def_align=&conference_game=&division_game=&tm_is_playoff=&opp_is_playoff=&tm_is_winning=&opp_is_winning=&tm_scored_first=&tm_led=&tm_trailed=&tm_won_toss=&c1stat=turnovers&c1comp=gt&c1val=5&c2stat=points_diff&c2comp=gt&c2val=0&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&c5comp=&c5gtlt=lt&c6mult=1.0&c6comp=&order_by=game_date), it is seven for the regular season and playoffs.  Three post-merger playoff games surpassed Seattle's five.

The Tennessee Titans defeated the Cleveland Browns on November 19, 2000, by the score of 24 to 10.  They committed seven turnovers to Cleveland's one, but thanks to Tennessee having Eddie George and Steve McNair, and Cleveland being, well, Cleveland, they still won the game handily.

Three other teams won the game with seven turnovers; Buffalo defeated NYG with 7 turnovers to the Giants' 2 in 1987, in a 6-3 overtime game involving 6 missed field goals (bet they wish they had Scott Norwood that day).  1983 featured the other two games, with PIT defeating the hapless Tampa Bay Buccaneers with a 7-0 turnover differential, and Miami defeated Kansas City in a turnover-filled game (12 total turnovers, 7 by the victorious Dolphins).

The only three playoff games with more turnovers than Seattle's defeat of the Packers, are a fairly well known [Superbowl](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197101170clt.htm), a less well known [Conference Championship](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/197601040pit.htm), and a game that should be [fairly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Catch_%28American_football%29) [familiar](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/boxscores/198201100sfo.htm) to NFL fans older than 35 or so.  Prior to [The Catch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EFsBSbx5UKY), the 49ers had six turnovers to Dallas's 3 in 1982.  During Superbowl V, the Colts had *seven* turnovers to Dallas's four.  Finally, in the 1975 season, the Steelers beat the Raiders 16-10, with 7 turnovers to Oakland's five.

Including all games since 1940:

[This Query](http://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1940&year_max=2014&game_type=&playoff_round=&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&game_day_of_week=&game_time=&time_zone=&game_location=&surface=&roof=&stadium_id=&temperature_gtlt=lt&temperature=&game_result=W&overtime=&league_id=&team_id=&team_conf_id=&team_div_id=&opp_id=&opp_conf_id=&opp_div_id=&team_off_scheme=&team_def_align=&opp_off_scheme=&opp_def_align=&conference_game=&division_game=&tm_is_playoff=&opp_is_playoff=&tm_is_winning=&opp_is_winning=&tm_scored_first=&tm_led=&tm_trailed=&tm_won_toss=&c1stat=turnovers&c1comp=gt&c1val=6&c2stat=points_diff&c2comp=gt&c2val=0&c3stat=&c3comp=gt&c3val=&c4stat=&c4comp=gt&c4val=&c5comp=&c5gtlt=lt&c6mult=1.0&c6comp=&order_by=turnovers) shows 3 teams with 9 turnovers in wins in the 40s and 50s.   One more playoff game has seven turnovers, but none have more.